# Strange Fatal error: Allowed memory size in composer file

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, bundle

i want to import a new bundle to my symfony project but i got this error :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Rule.php on line 60

i've tried to update the memory_limits to -1

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update
```

message:

> Nothing to install or update

i modified my composer.phar manually
same error.

Comment: what is you composer.json and what was the new bundle you added?#

Comment: Try a php composer.phar self-update

Comment: thanks for replies 
the new bundle is the vich/uploader-bundle and i'm sorry what do you mean with what is you composer.json? the version ? and if the version where i find it.

Comment: for self update 
Message 'You are already using composer version 1.3.2 (stable channel).'

Comment: composer.json is a file located at your project root level that states all the bundles you are trying to load and for what environment. For the Vich Uploader I would expect to see something like `"vich/uploader-bundle": "^0.14.0"`

Comment: it was in php.ini file i fixed that and i cleared the cach it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to run: composer install first, sometimes the app contains some errors that creates a infinite loop, and that cause the memory problem. If you found any error, solve it, and try to run: composer update again.